# VueJs Pass array of object to child component do not refresh on changes

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to pass an array of object to a childComponent as prop but when I add an object in it, it doesn't render. (Note: I'm working on vuejs 2.6)

I suppose it has a link with the "monitoring" of the items of the array and not the array itself? Stuff is that if I do not pass the prop and use the default value instead, it's working perfectly. I think I'm missing something here. Could someone help me ?

*By curiosity is this kind of behavior still stand with vue3js ?*

**As you can see below:**

[image]

**App.vue**:

```html
<template>
 <div id="app">
  <Card
   v-for="user in users"
   :key="user.userId"
   :userId="user.userId"
   :username="getUsernameFromUserId(user.userId)"
   :links="getUserLinksFromUserId(user.userId)"
  />
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from "./components/Card.vue";

export default {
 name: "App",
 components: {
  Card,
 },
 data: function () {
  return {
   users: [
    { userId: 1, name: "Bob" },
    { userId: 2, name: "Alice" },
    { userId: 3, name: "Eliot" },
   ],
   links: [
    { userId: 1, link: "hello->world" },
    { userId: 1, link: "world->!" },
    { userId: 3, link: "hello->back" },
    { userId: 4, link: "hello->you" },
   ],
  };
 },
 methods: {
  getUsernameFromUserId: function (userId) {
   return this.users.filter((obj) => obj.userId == userId)?.[0]?.name ?? "Not found";
  },
  getUserLinksFromUserId: function (userId) {
   return this.links.filter((obj) => obj.userId == userId);
  },
 },
};
</script>
```

**Card.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <h1>{{ username }}</h1>
    <button @click="addLink">Add One link</button><br><br>
    <span v-if="links.length == 0">No links</span>
    <div class="links">
        <Link v-for="link in links" :key="links.indexOf(link)" :link="link"></Link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Link from '../components/Link'

export default {
  components:{Link},
  props: {
    userId: Number,
    username: String,
    links: { type: Array, default: () => [], required: false },
  },
  methods:{
    addLink: function(){
      this.links.push({
        userId: this.userId,
        link: 'newlink->cool'
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Link.vue**

```html
<template>
 <div>
  <span>UserId: {{ this.link.userId }} Link: {{ this.link.link }</span>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 props: {
  link: { type: Object, default: () => [], required: false },
 },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad way to work with `props`

*Note: do not focus on Dev Tools too much as it can be "buggy" at times - especially if you use Vue in a wrong way. Focus on your app output*

1. Your `Card.vue` component is modifying (`push`) a prop, which is [not recommended](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) but it sort of works if the prop is object/Array and you do not replace it, just modify it's content (as you do)
2. **But** in your case, the values passed to props are actually generated by a `method`! The `getUserLinksFromUserId` method is generating a new array every time it is called, and this array **is NOT reactive**. So by pushing to it, your component will not re-render and what is worse, parent's `links` array is not changed at all! (on top of that - if `App.vue` ever re-renders, it will generate new arrays, pass it to pros and your modified arrys will be forgoten)

So intead of modifying `links` prop in `Card.vue`, just emit an event and do the modification in `App.vue`

Comment: Oh Yes I see, in the end its better to move the `getUserLinksFromUserId` in the `Card.vue`.
And If I need to add an item in the array I should emit an event from the child to ask the parent class to add it on top. Isn't ?

Comment: Regarding how to pass links, it is not that clear. You can pass all links to a `Card` and filter there (but instead of using method, `computed` would be more appropriate and more efficient)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as I read clearly, I suppose that this would happened as well with vue3js